# problem in finding integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

**Can this integral Converge,if it is then find the value
$\int_{0}^{\infty} ln(1-x)dx$**

But when $x \to \infty$ then $(1-x)\to -\infty$ but domain of $ln$ is $(0,\infty)$.How can I integrate?

Comment: integral doesn't even make sense, for the reason you gave

Comment: The domain of the integrand function is $(-\infty,1)$.